# How to make two random variables independent in R? (simulation)

Tags: panel

```
## eta
set.seed(20230615)
N <- 3
T <- 2
NT <- N*T
eta <- runif(N, min=0, max=1)
eta_mat <- matrix(eta, ncol=1)
eta_mat <- vec_rep_each(eta_mat, T) # to make it as column vector


## w
set.seed(123)
N <- 3
T <- 2
NT <- N*T
w <- matrix(0, nrow=NT, ncol=1)
w[1,] <- runif(1, min=-1, max=1)
w[2,] <- 0.5*w[1,] + runif(1, min=-1, max=1) # serial correlation assumption
w[3,] <- runif(1, min=-1, max=1)
w[4,] <- 0.5*w[3,] + runif(1, min=-1, max=1)
w[5,] <- runif(1, min=-1, max=1)
w[6,] <- 0.5*w[5,] + runif(1, min=-1, max=1)
```

I am trying to generate panel data. 'eta' is the individual effect and 'w' is remaining error term. 'w' is serially correlated. I draw from uniform distribution. There is one more assumption that eta and w should be uncorrelated. However, when I run 'cor.test(eta_mat, w)', it turns out that the correlation is -0.17, which is too high.

I don't know how to handle this problem exactly.